# Прикручивание домена к поддомену

Tags: домен, хостинг

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытие адреса domen.com отображался адрес shop.site.ru (Оба домена принадлежат мне).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы на domen.com хостинг не нужен был. И без переадресации, тоесть пользователь видит domen.com, а ему отображает содержимое shop.site.ru

Comment: @Дмитрий Малышев, вы, может быть, удосужитесь уже назвать свой веб-сервер? Апач? Энжин-икс?

Comment: если честно, то я еще не поставил свой сайт на хостинг, сейчас на виртуальном работаю. на виртуалке у меня стоит апач

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать на уровне регистратора домена. Есть такая услуга как перенаправление/forwarding, может быть платной или бесплатной все зависит от регистратора. Минус данной услуги в том что в адресной строке не будет изменений. Скажем если пользователь зашел на www.domain.com и дальше перешел на /news.html в адресной строке так и останется www.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

в .htaccess что надо прописать(если его нет, добавить) редирект 301. это должно быть на сайте с которого будет переадресация:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/старое_имя/(.*)$/ http://ввв.сайт.ру/новое_имя/$1 [R=301,L]
```